# What is the best way to write a regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Good day!

I don't know regular expressions very well, but I tried to compose one. I need this regular expression matched a record for example:

The user enters any value in the text field that can start with `00x00` and end with `12x99`, it must contain only the sign `"x"` and the first pair of numbers (the one before "x") must not exceed the number `"12"`.

I tried a record like this:

```
/^(00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)x([0-9]{2,2})&/
```

and it fits me, but it's too long expression, I'm sure there's something shorter. Asking for help from You !

Comment: I honestly think this is a pretty good regex. Sure, it can be a bit shorter, but it's now super clear what the allowed values are and this is a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten the expression quite a bit.

```
^(0\d|1[0-2])x\d{2}$
```

First you can remove the parenthesis around the entire expression, they are not required if you want a full match.

The you can replace every `[0-9]` block with the `\d` token.

Then the quantifier can be simplified if you want a strict quantity `{2,2}` to `{2}`

The first part is a bit more tricky. You can actually separate the match in 2 parts. You need to match every number from `00` to `09`, and every number from `10` to `12`.

So this is exactly what we are going to do.

First the match from `00` to `09`, the first digit doesn't change, so that's easy. The second digit is a full range from 0 to 9, so we use `\d` as previously mentioned. That gives us `0\d`.

The second half has the same fixed first digit, 1. Again that's easy. Then it's actually a shortened range from 0 to 2. That gives us `1[0-2]`.

Could be one or the other, so we encapsulate that part and use the `|` (or) token.

And that's it, we combine everything and get the expression above!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to *explain* your regex.... this is crucially important.

Comment: Thank you @Morphyish very much !
Sorry, I can't give you +1 point per answer because i don't have a reputation (

Comment: and sorry I just have a terrible English, but I study as best I can :(